# Как получить все столбцы таблицы по сочетанию значений двух столбцов?

Tags: sql, oracle

Как осуществить поиск по таблице по сочетаниям двух столбцов?

С помощью запроса:

```
select sb.col1, sb.col2 from table1 sb          
minus
select s.col1, s.col2 from table2 s
```

получаем таблицу из двух столбцов, показывающих уникальные сочетания `col1+col2` которые есть в `table1` и нет в `table2`. Все столбцы таблиц отличаются по формату, кроме `col1` и `col2`.

Как осуществить поиск в `table1` по этим уникальным сочетаниям?

Т.е. нужно вывести прочие столбцы для записей, которые есть в `table1` и нет в `table2`, где ключевым является сочетание значений столбцов `col1+col2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь CTE:

```
with tab as (
  select sb.col1, sb.col2 from table1 sb          
  minus
  select s.col1, s.col2 from table2 s
)
select
  * 
from table1 
where (col1, col2) in (select col1, col2 from tab)
;
```

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к [правильному ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1315918).

Также можно воспользоваться коррелированным запросом:

```sql
select t1.* from (
    select col1, col2 from t1          
    minus
    select col1, col2 from t2) t
cross apply (
    select * from t1
    where t1.col1 = t.col1 and t1.col2 = t.col2) t1
```

На таких тестовых данных:

```sql
with 
t1 (col1, col2, col3) as (
    select 1, 1, 't1-1-1' from dual union all 
    select 1, 2, 't1-1-2' from dual union all 
    select 1, 3, 't1-1-3' from dual),
t2 (col1, col2) as (    
    select 1, 1 from dual union all 
    select 2, 1 from dual)
<здесь запрос>
```

Будет получен ожидаемый результат:

```
      COL1       COL2 COL3  
---------- ---------- ------
         1          3 t1-1-3
         1          2 t1-1-2
```